# Select smallest angle between many vectors and my object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a array of vector3:

```
Vector3[]points
```

I have aimed point position stored in Vector3 variable:

```
Vector3 endPos
```

I need to get the smallest angle with aim point among the Vector3 array,and return the index of vector3 with smallest angle.

I'm thinking how to do it for few hours but I really don't know how. I am still a new one about this (Please in C#).Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Vector3.Angle()` to get the angle between two `Vector3` and iterate on your points and storing smallest degree and its index in a temporary variable.
Something like this:

```cs
Vector3 endPos;
Vector3[] points;
private void SmallestAngle()
{
    if(points.Length <2)
    {
        Debug.LogError("There should be more than two points!");
        return;
    }
    float deg = float.PositiveInfinity;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
    {

        float d = Vector3.Angle(points[i], endPos);
        if (d < deg)
        {
            deg = d;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    Debug.Log($"Smallest angle = {deg} / Index = {index}");
}
```

Comment: I'm glad that it's worked. You can select accept the answer. So other readers can find it easily.